# How do I filter log by folder in SourceTree?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

In SourceTree, how do I limit the log to only show commits that affected files within a given folder?

I.e. the equivalent to:
`git log path/to/folder`

Comment: Why not just use the command line, as you have shown?

Comment: @Cupcake Because I'm looking for a graphical alternative.

Comment: FYI, both the Windows and Mac version of SourceTree have this built-in now, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18172519/456814).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### This Answer is Outdated

This answer is now **outdated.** It was written ***before*** the Windows version of SourceTree had this feature built-in. The current version of SourceTree for Windows (1.5.2.0) has this feature now, so [@bozi's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18172519/456814) should now work for both the Windows and Mac versions of SourceTree.

### Original Answer

Instead of using SourceTree, you can use

```
gitk -- folderPath
```

to view the history of just the folder.  `gitk` takes many of the same options that `git log` does.

Another option is to use another Git gui like TortoiseGit, which will let you select folders in Windows Explorer and right-click to get a context menu, from which you can select to view the log for that one particular folder.

Comment: +1 the suggestion of gitk worked for actually logging a folder, the suggested answer doesn't log folders on my version.

Comment: If you're considering 'Instead of using SourceTree' solutions - `git log --pretty=oneline folderPath` also works, and doesn't need any tools that you might not have installed.

Comment: aaaaand, it's gone. Feature is not present in version 2.1.2.4

Answer (score 22):

Click on the **File Status** segmented control in the top left corner.

[image: Screenshot 1]

Above the **Files staged in the index** area set the filters to **Tree View** and **Show All**. All of your files will appear in the **Files in the working tree** area.

[image: Screenshot 2]

Select one or more files and/or folders, right click and select **Log Selected...**.

[image: Screenshot 3]

Comment: This is currently only possible on the Mac version. See https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/179045/is-there-a-explorer-finder-file-view-in-sourcetree

Comment: This is now possible on the Windows version of SourceTree, version 1.5.2.0.

Comment: This only shows a flat list of commits, I would have expected to see a log graph for commits in various branches where this file was also modified. I am unable to verify if this is showing logs for the file across all branches (similar to `git log --all -- <file>`).

Comment: You say it's possible to select one or more files, but the "Log Selected..." option is disabled if I select more than one file... 1.6.4.0 on Windows.

Comment: This does not work on 1.6.13.0 on Windows. "Log Selected..." is greyed out.

Comment: 1.6.14 on Windows: this option is available only for single files. Greyed out for folders.

Comment: While the text of this example claims that you can "log selected..." on a folder, the screen shots show selecting a single file.  Indeed, that is all that SourceTree for Windows seems to support, as "Log selected..." is grey for any folder in tree view, and when you select more than one file in flat view.

Comment: yep, does not work on directories (or multiple files in a directory for that matter). I don't see a technical reason why it'd be disabled when on a directory, seems a minor bug.

Comment: The question asks log by folder, not by file. As of Jan 2018, this is still not a supported feature in the Windows client. This is a feature I used heavily in Perforce; would like to see that in SourceTree as well.

Answer (score 3):

My first thought was, Log Selected feature is only for files.

Then accidentally I hit Tree View - Voila!

I am using Mac, not sure this is available on Windows.

- Change Source Tree settings to TreeView
- As explained by @bozi Click on Log Selected

[image]

Comment: This shows only the file under that folder which is present in the commit. this is not working

Comment: Not working, you cant' right click a folder and run a Log Selected action on it. It's grayed.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is no option for this at sourcetree. You can post this feature idea to the atlassian site.

Comment: FYI, this answer is much outdated now, both the Windows and Mac versions of SourceTree have this feature now.

Comment: Actually there IS NO option to filter commits by folder in SourceTree (@1.5.2). Yes, if I want to track history on a per file basis it works - but not for folders (a.k.a lots of files stored together, e.g. sub project).